# settings search like Google Chrome for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, user-interface

Chrome has an awesome feature: You can search the settings page, and Chrome displays only the relevant settings, or, if you need to open a window, a little hint. I really like this feature and would like to implement it in my Open-Source tool.

How could this be realized, technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using a collection view for your settings collection and filter this after you change the search string.

```
var settings = new ObservableCollection<SettingsClassType>();
SettingsCollView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(settings);
SettingsCollView.Filter += (o) => {
  var setting = (SettingsClassType)o;
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(YourSearchInput)
         || setting.Name.Contains(YourSearchInput);
}

private string yourSearchInput;
public bool YourSearchInput
{
  get { return yourSearchInput; }
  set
  {
    if (value == yourSearchInput) {
      return;
    }
    yourSearchInput= value;
    // filer your collection here
    SettingsCollView.Refresh();
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("YourSearchInput");
  }
}
```

hope that helps